# how do i sum duplicate array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, filtering

the program works fine, except that the "change" array has many duplicates, summing the duplicates is supposed to be easy, except it gives wrong sums!
ex: summing 3 twenties should give 60, instead it gives 80!
i noticed that the error only happens with the odd duplicates!
another thing that i cant figure out is why the "change" array is changing when i sum the duplicates? i copied the change array to a different array so if anything happens to the 2nd array it shouldnt affect "change" array!

the program works well until i get to the part where i need to sum the duplicates (sumDuplicates() function works fine on its own, but not with my code)

```js
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  var change = [];
  let difference = cash - price;
  let level = 0;
  let currency = [
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["NICKEL", 0.05],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["TEN", 10],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
  ]
  //sum all money in register
  let totalFunds = cid.reduce((r, [key, value]) => {
    return r + value
  }, 0)

  //function to match the difference to appropriate currency
  function findLevel(dif) {
    for (let i = currency.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      //our change must be the highest availabe currency
      if (dif >= currency[i][1] && cid[i][1] != 0) {
        //console.log(currency[i])
        return i
      }
    }
  }
  //function to subtract
  function subtractor(dif, lvl) {
    if (cid[lvl][1] != 0) {
      dif = dif.toFixed(2)
      dif = dif - currency[lvl][1]
      cid[lvl][1] -= currency[lvl][1]
      change.push(currency[lvl])
      return dif
    }
  }
  //if no change needed
  if (difference == 0) {
    return {
      status: "CLOSED",
      change: []
    }
  }
  //if we dont have enough money to pay back
  if (totalFunds < difference) {
    return {
      status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS",
      change: []
    }
  }
  //if we need to pay change AND we have enough money
  if (difference > 0 && totalFunds >= difference) {
    while (difference >= 0.01) {
      level = findLevel(difference)
      difference = subtractor(difference, level)
      //console.log(difference)
    }
  }

  //to sum duplicate elements in the "change" array, this is the problem!!!
  function sumDuplicates(arr1) {
    let arr = [...arr1]
    let sums = arr.reduce((sums, item) => {
      let found = sums.find(([key]) => key === item[0]);
      //console.log(found)
      if (found)
        found[1] += item[1];
      else
        sums.push(item);
      // console.log(item)
      return sums;
    }, []);
    return sums;
  }
  let sums = sumDuplicates(change)
  console.log(sums);
  return {
    status: "OPEN",
    change: sums
  };
}

checkCashRegister(3.26, 100, [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
]);
```

I expect `[[twenties,60]]` instead I get `[[twenties,80]]`

Comment: @Bosco The code was already indented using the snippet editor's Tidy function. Why did you need to remove the snippet to fix the indentation?

Comment: The edit happened simultaneously. needs to roll back or repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful with pushing references into arrays, because they don't make copies. You do it in an couple places and in your `sum` function you end up modifying the original array which changes the values in your lookup table.

```
if (found)
     found[1] += item[1]; // <-- now modifying your original currency lookup!
else
     sums.push(item);     // <-- your pushing a ref to your original currency lookup!
```

A quick fix is to push a copy instead in your sum function:

```
 sums.push([...item])
```

A (probably better alternative) is to push a copy into the `change` array:

```
function subtractor(dif, lvl) {
  if (cid[lvl][1] != 0) {
      dif = dif.toFixed(2)
      dif = dif - currency[lvl][1]
      cid[lvl][1] -= currency[lvl][1]
      change.push([...currency[lvl]]) // < push a copy not the original ref
      return dif
   }
 }
```

```js
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  var change = [];
  let difference = cash - price;
  let level = 0;
  let currency = [
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["NICKEL", 0.05],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["TEN", 10],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
  ]
  //sum all money in register
  let totalFunds = cid.reduce((r, [key, value]) => {
    return r + value
  }, 0)

  //function to match the difference to appropriate currency
  function findLevel(dif) {
    for (let i = currency.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      //our change must be the highest availabe currency
      if (dif >= currency[i][1] && cid[i][1] != 0) {
        //console.log(currency[i])
        return i
      }
    }
  }
  //function to subtract
  function subtractor(dif, lvl) {
    if (cid[lvl][1] != 0) {
      dif = dif.toFixed(2)
      dif = dif - currency[lvl][1]
      cid[lvl][1] -= currency[lvl][1]
      change.push([...currency[lvl]])  //< -- PUSH A COPY!
      return dif
    }
  }
  //if no change needed
  if (difference == 0) {
    return {
      status: "CLOSED",
      change: []
    }
  }
  //if we dont have enough money to pay back
  if (totalFunds < difference) {
    return {
      status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS",
      change: []
    }
  }
  //if we need to pay change AND we have enough money
  if (difference > 0 && totalFunds >= difference) {
    while (difference >= 0.01) {
      level = findLevel(difference)
      difference = subtractor(difference, level)
      //console.log(difference)
    }
  }

  //to sum duplicate elements in the "change" array, this is the problem!!!
  function sumDuplicates(arr1) {
    let arr = [...arr1]
    let sums = arr.reduce((sums, item) => {
      let found = sums.find(([key]) => key === item[0]);
      //console.log(found)
      if (found)
        found[1] += item[1];
      else
        sums.push(item);  
      // console.log(item)
      return sums;
    }, []);
    return sums;
  }
  let sums = sumDuplicates(change)
  console.log(sums);
  return {
    status: "OPEN",
    change: sums
  };
}

console.log(checkCashRegister(3.26, 100, [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
]));
```